Difficulties in using exogenous variables for time series forecasting
I have a slight confusion when time series modeling using exogenous variables. Suppose I am modeling housing price, and one of my exogenous variables is 'housing type' with value 'unit' or 'house'. When forecasting the into the future, the value being forecasted is obviously housing price.
How am I to determine what the value of the housing type is for the future? Should I train 2 separate models for each housing type and throw away the variable entirely? Or do I just not try to make assumption on what the value of 'housing type' is?

If you have prices for two types of houses then it seems you have two time series, one for each type.

thanks. this is what i figured
